# show login on home page

Tags: asp.net

i have a login page login.aspx, a loginstatus in masterpage when i click to login link the page is redirected to login.aspx and user can login from this page..now i want that instead of login link on default page there should be username and password textboxes on the default page itself and the user is able to login on the default page itself..therefore now the user will login through the default as well as login page

Comment: so what's the issue with you??

Comment: i jst want to know that will it be same if user logins through default page or login page

Comment: yah, it will be same, I don't think there will be an issue.

Comment: ok let me try,thnx for d suggestion

Comment: Sumit What is the issue tell us in detail?

Comment: actually i wasnt sure that if i add login in default page and a separate page for login then will both serve the same purpose or not

Comment: first you need to try and if you have some problem then let us know

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the ASP.NET login controls, and they are configured similarly (i.e. using the same membership provider, etc), then yes, they will both serve the same purpose.

You could easily wrap the login controls inside of a [LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) control:

```
<asp:LoginView id="LoginViewWithLogin" runat="server">
  <AnonymousTemplate>
    <asp:Login id="HomePageLogin" runat="server" />
  </AnonymousTemplate>
  <LoggedInTemplate>
    Welcome back <asp:LoginName id="HomePageLoginName" runat="server" />.
    <asp:LoginStatus id="HomePageLogout" runat="server" 
                     logoutText="Click here to logout" />
  </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

This would show the login controls to anonymous users, while welcoming back logged in users and offering them the chance to logout.

If you want to replace the LoginStatus link with the Login control on the homepage, you'll need to add some logic to your Master Page to hide out the standard LoginStatus control and display the LoginView instead.